# Android [LocationManager] requestLocationUpdates(), java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager, runtimeexception

I am getting this error when requestion for location updates inside `service`. Location permission is granted, `LocationManager` is not null, `Provider` is not null.

```
LocationManager: [LocationManager] requestLocationUpdates(), 
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:1013)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:595)
        at com.trackinglibrary.service.DataService.createAndRequestLocationUpdates(DataService.java:759)
        at com.trackinglibrary.service.DataService.onStartCommand(DataService.java:252)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3694)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:202)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Location code that I am calling inside  `onStartCommand()`:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void createAndRequestLocationUpdates() {
        try {

            if (!TrackThatUtils.isLocationEnabled(getApplicationContext())) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Location is disable.");
                return;
            }

            if (locationManager == null) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                addProximityAlert();
            }

            if (locationManager == null || !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Location provider is disable.");
                return;
            }

            // getting GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Log.e(TAG, "Location provider is: " + isGPSEnabled);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                Log.e(TAG, "== Error On onConnected() Permission not granted");
                //Permission not granted by user so cancel the further execution.
                return;
            }


            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
            //setCostAllowed(true): This flag enables LocationManager to exchange “data packet” with
            // 3G/4G network base stations in order to get better location
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

            //API level 9 and up
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
            criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);

            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

//          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(gpsFreqInMillis, gpsFreqInDistance, criteria, locationListener, null);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, this);
            Log.i(TAG, "request for location updates..");
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception inside createAndRequestLocationUpdates(): " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405393/location-updates-not-working-on-allowing-runtime-permission/50406238#50406238

Comment: check my answer , its a complete solution with run time permissions using google api client , try it and let me know if it helps

Comment: possibly you are calling `requestLocationUpdates` from any handler/thread. try to replace your calling method inside onCreate() of your Activity or Fragment.

Comment: @Quicklearner Thanks for quick reply. I am using this code inside service and I am using LocationManager not fused API

Comment: using google api client is a good and safe technique :) i would say a good practice

Comment: okay but at this point, I am using android's Location API inside service and in Android Pie it is giving me the above exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022662/android-locationmanager-vs-google-play-services

Comment: you can use the google fused api in service too , not an issue i think

Comment: I know that but i need only gps data and fused api used almost all provider(gps,network,sensor etc).

Comment: @Quicklearner If you have any solution to this exception please address me. Thanks :)

Comment: sure i will have to check and implement that in service class

Comment: @Rahul have you got solution for this issue?. If it so,please post the solution

Comment: @vimalraj please see my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't store [Location](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/api/gbase/client/Location) class in shared preferences In my case this was the problem

Comment: I have not stored location in shared preference

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%2520long,%2520float,%2520android.location.LocationListener)) `RuntimeException` is called when calling thread has no Looper. Try to call `Looper.prepare()` before you call `LocationManager`

Comment: No, the Looper is called by default in any Android Activity and Service.